# How can I find the index of element in a database while querying only a few at at time?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, algorithm, elasticsearch, search, searchkick

I'm having some trouble trying to find a good and efficient algorithm for my use case.

Basically, I'm running a search into a database with ElasticSearch via Rails, and we have it set so that it can only return 25 results at a time (out of an approximate total of 5000), starting with the ID that you input (specified by a `search_after` parameter). I'm also inputting the ID of a certain search result, which I want the index of inside the overall database. The search has no way of knowing which page (of 25 results) it's actually on. We also have methods for finding the results immediately before and after it (which could probably also be modified to get results up to 25 before and after), regardless if it's on the first "page" (i.e. has an index of say, 26) or not.

Thus, it's fairly easy for the first 25 since you can simply do a search_after with the very first item in the overall database, but after that, I don't really know how to proceed.

I'd thought about simply upping the number of results to 26, then using modular arithmetic to check if it's the (n%25==1)th result, then changing the `search_after` to become the (n-1)th result, but I realized it wouldn't work if you directly click on any result after the first one to appear on the page. I also thought maybe I could use the aforementioned method to get the immediately previous search result and do a `search_after` on that, but then I quickly realized it would just return a 1 every time. Finally, I thought of simply stepping up the search_after until it finds the ID as the last result of the 25, and then using arithmetic to figure out what index it is, but obviously that's incredibly computationally intensive.

Let me know if any clarifications are needed, because I know it's a kind of odd question. Thank you.

Comment: what do you need the index for?

Comment: I'm making a counter at the top of the page to show which result you're on (e.g. 50/5000)